# Low level acces of HttpWebRequest request/response from C#

Tags: c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

I do http get request in C#/.Net 4.0 using code like this:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

but I also need to monitor complete low level data (undecoded header and body) of request/response in my own code.

Is there a way to do it easily (ie without using something like FiddlerCore) in .Net ?

Comment: You could socket programming and create the complete HTTP request packets and recieve the response packets. Why do you need to monitor the low-level stuff anyway ?

Comment: @ryadavilli HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse is easy to use with lots of power. I prefer to stay at this level without go to the metal with socket programming. But I need to monitor low level data to be able to implement my own caching mechanism and for debugging purpose.

Comment: I'll try to investigate using System.Net.Trace from my own code.